# Can we Resize the jLayer to required Width and height so that all the elements in that jLayer component can resized and aligned

Tags: java, swing, resize, jlayer

I have a JLayer with 1500 width and 1050 height . I would like to resize the Jlayer to 1016x724.

Comment: Isn't the size of the layer depended on the size of the component it's wrapping?

Comment: Yes it is. With Affine Transformation I translate and scaled the components . So as a result it returns a JLayer . But that resulted JLayer is (width=1728,height=1231)   which exceed my device screen so I would like to resize to 1350x724.

Comment: Maybe change the scaling instead

Comment: Why is the JLayer that size? Just add the JLayer to the BorderLayout of the frame and the layer will automatically be resized to the space available to the frame so it will work on all resolutions.